# Spark2.3.0-bin-without-hadoop, docker-image-tool.sh missing hadoop jars

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, docker, dockerfile

I am trying to build spark container images for deployment in kubernetes and suspect I am doing it wrong. I am getting the following error when running the images:

```
   /opt/spark/conf/spark-env.sh: line 72: /home/me/hadoop_s3/bin/hadoop: No such file or directory
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/Logger
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Class.java:3048)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:3018)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1784)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(LauncherHelper.java:544)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:526)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.slf4j.Logger
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 7 more
```

The above comes from inspecting failures logs from the init-container in my failed k8s pod. Note that the first line shows my error - the spark-env.sh inside the container is referencing a hadoop location that doesn't exist in the container.

Since I am using the "without-hadoop" version of Spark, what seems to be happening is that the hadoop jars aren't packaged in the container built by docker-image-tool.sh.

From my naive inspection of that script, I don't see a way it would work in fact.

My questions -

Are there additional steps to build an image that includes the external hadoop jars?

Is creating a spark container image using the without-hadoop build expected to work or is this a known limitation?

Comment: What do you mean by "without Hadoop?"
Did you download spark from official page? https://spark.apache.org/downloads.html If so, no further steps required.

Comment: Yes, I downloaded from the official page. In the "package type" drop-down, the package is called "Pre build with user-provided Hadoop". When you download, the actual filename is "spark-2.3.0-bin-without-hadoop.tgz"

Comment: @joshuarobinson I'm running into this exact same issue. Did you ever figure it out?

Comment: I've been trying to replicate this: http://beadooper.com/?p=459. It includes information regarding the inclusion of additional jars. I verified that this works on a VM, but building a docker image doesn't work

Comment: @joshuarobinson For me it was an issue with JAVA_HOME.

Comment: Hi, brief update. I have switched to using a different version of Spark (spark-2.3.0-bin-hadoop2.7) and have gotten past this issue (though unfortunately it still doesn't work, but for new reasons).

Answer (score 0):

Adding Hadoop library jars to Spark classpath will resolve the problem. But you might be facing other errors after this. Spark used many Hadoop libraries. use spark built with Hadoop instead of spark without Hadoop. Spark with Hadoop contains all Hadoop dependencies jars along with it.